# google plus generated comment id

Tags: javascript, php

I have small piece of parameter which is posting comment from Google plus.

below parameter

```
'["xxxxxxxxxxxx","os:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:1388057844981","xxxxxx ",1388057849783,null,2,null,null,[1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,[0,360,520]]]'
```

In this parameter i got two random number (1388057844981 and 1388057849783)

I didn't know how to generate this two numbers?

Can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the context at all, but the numbers look like the UNIX timestamp in milliseconds. I. e.:

```
$ date -R -d @1388057844 # 981 omitted
Thu, 26 Dec 2013 12:37:24 +0100
$ date -R -d @1388057849 # 783 omitted
Thu, 26 Dec 2013 12:37:29 +0100
```

Since it's today's date, it doesn't seem very random.